# creating userid on dialogflow using twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, dialogflow-es

please help. Im trying to make user specific userid on dialogflow using twilio integration with OriginalDetectIntentRequest. 
I am trying to do this in fullfillment. So a Node.js solution would be best
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i used $"let userID = request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.SmsSid;"

Comment: i get this error: TypeError: handler.get(...) is not a function
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:303:44)

Comment: I kind of need a bit more information then that. Can you edit your question with the full code that you've used and how you've configured it. Then let me know and I'll have a look.